# Communication between a Java TCP nio server and python2.7 client

Tags: java, python-2.7, tcp, nio, bytebuffer

I'm trying to send data from a python client to a java nio server. I tried to do this with normal socket program on python side as
 sock.send(data). The size of data in bytes was around 28000. But the return value of sock.send(data) was only 27120 (i.e.) the byte transferred is only 27120 bytes. On java nio side my butebuffer size is 32000. I receive data on java side as channel.read(readBuffer). Here also when I print readBuffer.position() after read it shows only 27120. My question is that if in python sys.getsizeof(data) gave 28000 and readBuffer size on java is 32kB, then the whole 28000 should have been received in readBuffer,but it shows only 27120 bytes have been read. How does this work. I'm new to this TCP nio concept. So please help me woth this for  better understanding.

**JAVA NIO server code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TCPnio
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

            try{
                    TCPServer tcpl = new TCPServer();
                    tcpl.init();
                    while(true)
                    {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
    }
}

class TCPServer implements Runnable 
{   
private Selector selector;
private ThreadPoolExecutor DataProcessingPool;
private Selector readSelector;
    private boolean readThreadStarted = false;
private int port = 4243;

private BlockingQueue infoQueue;

SocketChannelReader reader = null;  

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TCPnio.class.getName());


public void init()throws Exception
{
    infoQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(15470);
    DataProcessingPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0,40,0l,TimeUnit.MINUTES,infoQueue);

    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    selector = Selector.open();
    serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port),100);
    serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    new Thread(this,"mi-listener-tcp-"+port+"-thread").start();
    readSelector = Selector.open();

    // Starting a thread to read client socketChannel from selector
    serverChannel.register(readSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    reader = this.new SocketChannelReader(readSelector);
    new Thread(reader,"mi-reader-tcp-4243-thread").start();


}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        listen(selector);
    }
    catch(Exception excp)
    {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"",excp);
    }
}


class SocketChannelReader implements Runnable
{

    private Selector selector;

    public SocketChannelReader(Selector key)
    {
        this.selector = key;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
        LOG.info("started selector thread read");
        while(true)
        {
            selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                SelectionKey key =  it.next();
                it.remove();

                try
                {
                    if(key.isReadable())
                    {
                        handleRead(key);
                    }
                }
                catch(RejectedExecutionException e)
                {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Job submission failed");
                }
                catch(Exception excp)
                {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Error.",excp);//No I18N
                    close(key);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Exception in reader thread",e);
        }
    }
}

private void listen(Selector selector) throws Exception
{
    LOG.info("started selector thread listen");
    while(true)
    {
        selector.select();
        Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            SelectionKey key =  it.next();
            it.remove();

            try
            {
                if(key.isAcceptable())
                {
                    handleAccept(key,readSelector); //put readselector for single thread                        

                    if(!(readThreadStarted))
                    {
                        new Thread(reader,"mi-reader-tcp-4243-thread").start();
                        readThreadStarted = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception excp)
            {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Error.",excp);//No I18N
                close(key);
            }
        }
    }
}



private void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws Exception
{
    Session session =(Session)key.attachment(); // Session is another java class 
    ByteBuffer buffer=session.readBuffer; // 32011 bytes has been allocated for readBuffer
    System.out.println("------------------------- Buffer before read --------------------------------->");
            System.out.println(buffer.limit());
            System.out.println(buffer.position());
            System.out.println(buffer.capacity());
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------>");
    SocketChannel channel=(SocketChannel)key.channel();
    Socket socket = channel.socket();
    int bytesRead=channel.read(buffer);
    if(bytesRead==-1)
    {
        LOG.info("HandleRead closing key for "+socket.getPort());
        close(key);
        return;
    }
    processClientData(key,buffer,session,socket);
}


private void processClientData(SelectionKey key, ByteBuffer buffer, Session session, Socket socket) throws Exception
{

    String resp;
    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    try
    {

        System.out.println("------------------Buffer after read---------------------------------------->");         
                    System.out.println(buffer.limit());
        System.out.println(buffer.position());
                System.out.println(buffer.capacity());
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------->");


        String firstByte = String.valueOf((char) (buffer.get(0)));
        boolean isLastChunk = (firstByte).equals("1");

        byte[] tmpArr= new byte[session.payloadLength];
        for(int i=1;i<=session.payloadLength;i++)
        {               
            tmpArr[i-1] = buffer.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(new String(tmpArr));
        int dataLength = Integer.valueOf(new String(tmpArr));

        buffer.flip();

        if(buffer.remaining()==0)
        {               
            buffer.clear();
            return;
        }

        // To remove the initial bytes which are not part of data (The one's which gives data length)
        for(int i=0;i<=session.payloadLength;i++)
        {
            buffer.get();
        }

        int buffRem = buffer.remaining();
        byte[] data = new byte[buffRem];

        buffer.get(data);
        System.out.println(buffer.position());

        buffer.clear(); // Clearing buffer
                    System.out.println("----------------->Position:");
        System.out.println(buffer.position());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------->");

        session.key = key;
        session.processData(data, isLastChunk);

    }
    catch(Exception excp)
    {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"Going to close client "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+" "+socket.getPort()+" since got exception.",excp);
        excp.printStackTrace();
        resp = "500";
        sendResponse(client, resp);
        close(key);
    }
}
private void handleAccept(SelectionKey key,Selector readSelector) throws Exception
{
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocket=(ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
    SocketChannel socketCh=serverSocket.accept();
    socketCh.finishConnect();
    socketCh.configureBlocking(false);
    Socket socket=socketCh.socket();
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);//TODO Check if this works. Is it needed?

    System.out.println("--------------------------------->Going to reg:");  
    SelectionKey readKey=socketCh.register(readSelector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    Session session = new Session(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(),DataProcessingPool);
    readKey.attach(session);
    readKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    LOG.info("handleAccept complete with "+key);
}

private void sendResponse(SocketChannel client, String resp)
{

    Socket socket = client.socket();
    try
    {
        ByteBuffer sendBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        sendBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(resp.getBytes());
        client.write(sendBuffer);
        sendBuffer.clear();
    }
    catch(Exception excp)
    {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception in sending response client "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+" "+socket.getPort()+" in TCPlistner.",excp);
    }

}
private void close(SelectionKey key)
{
    Session session=(Session)key.attachment();
    try
    {
        LOG.info("closing in TCPnio for "+session);
        Channel ch=key.channel();
        //session.close();
        key.cancel();
        ch.close();
    }
    catch(Exception excp)
    {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Closing key in TCPnio for "+session,excp);
    }
}
```

}

**Python client code:**

```
def _send_data(self, param_type, data):

    resp = ''
    try:
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._sock.settimeout(15)
        self._sock.connect(('',4243))
        print "Socket established for "+str(self._sock.getsockname())+"..."

        print param_type
        tmp_param_type = param_type

        #data = "Hello l"#d!!! Hello world!!!"
        #param_type_data = ('0'*(self._max_payload_len - len(str(len(param_type)))))  + str(len(param_type)) + param_type
        #data = ('0'*(self._max_payload_len - len(str(len(param_type)))))  + str(len(param_type)) + param_type

        data_len = len(data)
        import sys
        #print sys.getsizeof(data)-sys.getsizeof(str())
        print '------------->Len:',len(data) # Length of data=26244

        end_idx = 0
        finaldataToSnd = ""

        while end_idx < data_len:
            islast = '0'

            if tmp_param_type:
            param_type_data = ('0'*(self._max_payload_len - len(str(len(tmp_param_type)))))  + str(len(tmp_param_type))
            param_type_data += tmp_param_type
            else:
                param_type_data = '00000'
            byteRem = self._max_datalen - len(tmp_param_type)
            strt_idx = end_idx
            end_idx = strt_idx + byteRem

            if end_idx >= data_len:
                end_idx = data_len
                islast = '1'

            content_length = (end_idx - strt_idx)+len(tmp_param_type)
            tmp_param_type=''
            content_length_data = ('0' * (self._max_payload_len - len(str(content_length)))) + str(content_length)

            #print sys.getsizeof(content_length_data)-sys.getsizeof(str())  

            dataToSnd = islast + content_length_data + param_type_data
            print sys.getsizeof(data[strt_idx:end_idx])-sys.getsizeof(str())
            dataToSnd = dataToSnd + data[strt_idx:end_idx]
            finaldataToSnd += dataToSnd


        print len(finaldataToSnd) # after adding header and all to data length is 26273
        print self._sock.send(finaldataToSnd) # No.of bytes sent shows as 21720
        resp = self._sock.recv(1024)
        self._sock.close()
        print "Socket closed..."
except:
    print traceback.print_exc() 
return resp
```

**Code explanation:**

A data given to python client will be sent to java server with extra added characters which determines the content-length,header-length and header of the data. So in my case I'm trying to send data of length 26244. The header to be sent is `param_type:machine`. So the data to be sent will have extra 29 characters(where 18 is for header and 11 to determine content length od header length). This data will be processed on java side for every 32011 bytes since byteBuffer allocated size is 32000 bytes.

Comment: show us the code you've been using, otherwise it's hard to speculate about what your code is doing or why.

Comment: There are no messages in TCP, and no guarantee that one write = one read. You will just have to keep reading until you have everything you need.